# insert multiple data into mysql table in single form with codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have this table in my View that contains the single form.
like below . in this table , I show all rows of one of my table of database and showing it to the user . then user must fill empty inputs of this form and then hit the submit button to submit the form and then I update the table in my controller with new data that user filled recently.

```
<table id="myTable" class="display">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>آیدی</th>
                        <th>کد پرسنلی</th>
                        <th>نام</th>
                        <th>نام خانوادگی</th>
                        <th>روزانه</th>
                        <th>لیست</th>
                        <th>سرویس</th>
                        <th>سایر</th>
                        <th>جمع</th>
                        <th>آسفالت</th>
                        <th>توقف شب</th>
                        <th>غیبت</th>
                        <th>کمک هزینه تست</th>
                        <th>توضیحات</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php if (isset($allReadyTasks) and $allReadyTasks) { ?>
                        <?php foreach ($allReadyTasks as $task): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $task->id;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $task->personalCode;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $task->fname;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $task->lname;?></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control taskInputs" value="<?php  echo $task->daily; ?>"</td>
                                <td><input class="form-control taskInputs" value="<?php  echo $task->list; ?>"</td>
                                <td><input class="form-control taskInputs" value="<?php  echo $task->service; ?>"</td>
                                <td><input class="form-control taskInputs" value="<?php  echo $task->other; ?>"</td>
                                <td><input class="form-control taskInputs" value="<?php  echo $task->sum; ?>"</td>
                                <td><input class="form-control taskInputs" value="<?php  echo $task->asphalt; ?>"</td>
                                <td><input class="form-control taskInputs" value="<?php  echo $task->nightPause; ?>"</td>
                                <td><input class="form-control taskInputs" value="<?php  echo $task->absent; ?>"</td>
                                <td><input class="form-control taskInputs" value="<?php  echo $task->allowance; ?>"</td>
                                <td><textarea class="form-control"></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php } ?>


                    </tbody>
                    </form>
                </table>
```

my question is : all the inputs have the save name . how can I update the all rows of my table of database with one form and inputs that have same name .!?

Comment: same name will overwrite the value with last input field

Comment: Change name to array name and use foreach loop in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="inputs[]"/>
```

After that,when you get it with POST, you will have an array of inputs and you can loop throw it with a `foreach`.